# Can't install - Oops at step three

Tags: error, install

I’m a would-be first-time Craft user. I’m trying to set up a first trial site but not having much success.

I’ve been trying to install Craft CMS on my host provider’s server. I use SmartHosting/Krystal as hosting provider.

I’ve gone through the install instructions and get as far as step three. On step three it blinks on ‘Installing Craft CMS’ for about half a second before changing to ‘Oops.’  With the circular timer beneath, it just stays on this “forever”.

When I search for this issue, there are quite a few mentions of this being a problem with Dreamhost (hosting service provider) so I have taken this up with my service provider in case it’s a similar issue. They have tried the same installation procedure on my behalf and get the same problem.  Their last reply to me is as below.

Can you help me solve my install problem?

+++++

Having spent some time on this for you I'm not entirely sure what's causing this issue. the CraftCMS system isn't outputting any PHP errors and I can't see any errors on the server logs either. Progressing this I'd have to recommend reaching out to craftcms support to find out if there's any known issues or if they can assist in debugging this issue for you.

++++

PS One possibility is that the install did work after all and the oops message is erroneous. Is there a simple way to find out if it did in fact work OK?

Comment: Open your network tab in your browser and see the exact response. Usually there is a message since this is an ajax request. You could check if it was successfully when you open your database. Are there any tables or is it still empty? Does your provider fulfill all the requirements?

Comment: Hi Robin, Thanks for this. Not sure what you mean by open network tab, sorry. Yes, the table craft_assetfiles has been created.My provider says that they fulfill all the requirements. I'm not sure I fully understand the notes in the installation instructions on file permissions but dont think there should be an issue there as have been successfully using Perch for sometime and it has similar notes about permissions.

Comment: The Craft installation functions are triggered with ajax requests and you can see them in your dev console within your browser. Press F12 (mostly) or check a tutorial for your specific browser how to open your development tools. For chrome it looks like that https://i.imgur.com/EiuxxW8.png. Go to the "network" tab and check all your requests (you must open the console before you press the "start installation/continue" button. When the error appears check the last rows
 in the network table and check the request, maybe make some screenshots if you don't know what these values mean.

Comment: The result of the last request is '500 Internal Server Error'. I also have a screengrab but unsure where to post that.

Comment: Do you see anything in the preview or response tab like you see in my screenshot? You can upload it here https://imgur.com/upload ahh that reminds me... go to the `/craft/config/generel.php` and activate the `devMode` flag

Comment: Hi Robin, it was 'table already exists' and now I understand. When I first ran the installation I had guessed at the user's db priveleges (based on another CMS) as I couldnt find the Craft ones at the time. So that created the table but with the wrong priveleges. Each time I subsequently ran it, it failed as the table already existed.

Comment: ... so I dropped the table and ran it again and it's worked fine.

Comment: @a1mark Would you mind adding what worked for you as an official answer in case it ends up helping someone in the future?

Comment: Of course Brad, it was as described above. Can you point me at how add an official answer please? First time on here. Cheers - Mark

Comment: @a1mark There's a "Your Answer" heading towards the bottom of this page with a text areas you can enter what worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

it was 'table already exists' and now I understand. When I first ran the installation I had guessed at the user's db priveleges (based on another CMS) as I couldnt find the Craft ones at the time. So that created the table but with the wrong privileges. Each time I subsequently ran it, it failed as the table already existed. – a1mark Oct 22 at 8:48